# Reusing UICollectionViewCell is overlaying their drawRects

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, drawrect

I have a collectionView showing different Cards in CardCells with a CardLayout.

Each cell should display a certain kind of colored shape. It should never show multiple colors.

When I scroll down & scroll up, I see multiple colors overlaid.  I think this is because of dequeue. I've tried painting over a rectangle with `CGContext` and `clear:frame` with `CGContext`, both have no (apparent) effect.

[image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "card", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
        c.card = deck.active[indexPath.row]
        c.cardLayout = cardLayout
        c.setNeedsDisplay()
        return c
    }

class CardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var card = Card()
    var cardLayout = CardLayout()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func getCenter() -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        cardLayout.render(c: c!, card: card, frame: frame)
    }


}

class CardLayout: NSObject {
    func color(i: Int) -> UIColor {
        return [1: UIColor.red, 2: UIColor.green, 4: UIColor.blue][i]!
    }

    func getCenter(frame: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    }

    func quantity(i: Int) -> Int {
        return [1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 3][i]!
    }

    func loadPath(c: CGContext, card: Card) {
        if card.fill == 1 {
            c.setFillColor(color(i: card.color).cgColor)
        } else {
            c.setStrokeColor(color(i: card.color).cgColor)
        }
    }

    func drawPath(c: CGContext, card: Card) {
        if card.fill == 1 {
            c.fillPath()
        } else {
            c.strokePath()
        }
    }

    func render1(c: CGContext, card: Card, frame: CGRect, y: CGFloat) {
        c.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: y) , radius: frame.size.width / 10, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360 * 3.142 / 180, clockwise: true)
    }

    func render2(c: CGContext, card: Card, frame: CGRect, y: CGFloat) {
        let m = frame.size.width / 2
        let size = CGFloat(10)
        c.move(to: CGPoint(x: m, y: y - size))
        c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: m - size, y: y + size))
        c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: m + size, y: y + size))
        c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: m, y: y - size))
    }

    func render3(c: CGContext, card: Card, frame: CGRect, y: CGFloat) {
    }

    func render(c: CGContext, card: Card, frame: CGRect) {
        let size = frame.size.height / 6
        var num = quantity(i: card.quantity)

        var sy = size
        if num == 1 {
            sy = frame.size.height / 2
        } else if num == 2 {
            sy = (frame.size.height / 2) - (size * 0.5)
        } else if num == 3 {
            sy = (frame.size.height / 2) - size
        }

        while num > 0 {
            c.beginPath()
            c.addRect(frame)
            c.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
            c.fillPath()
            c.beginPath()
            loadPath(c: c, card: card)
            if card.shape == 1 {
                render1(c: c, card: card, frame: frame, y: sy)
            } else if card.shape == 2 {
                render2(c: c, card: card, frame: frame, y: sy)
            } else if card.shape == 3 {
//                render3(c: c, card: card, frame: frame, y: sy)
            }
            drawPath(c: c, card: card)

            num = num - 1
            sy = sy + size
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `cardLayout` in your `cellForItemAt` method? You need to have a `cardLayout` specific to the given index path.

Comment: CardLayout is set in viewDidLoad with         `cardLayout = CardLayout()`. I don't see why I need as pecific one? CardLayout is a set of functions describing how to draw (it could easily be static). It renders fine the first time, only after scrolling is there an issue. I've fixed the problem by using custom Identifiers for each cell but I'd like to know the real fix.

Comment: But every one of your cells is using that one card layout, over and over. How can that be correct?

Comment: Because the cardLayout takes in a card to decide how to render. `func render(c: CGContext, card: Card, frame: CGRect) {` it's in the code - it renders differently each time. This displays correctly the FIRST time it draws. When I scroll down & up it's a problem. It's definitely related to re-use // not clearing old draws

Comment: You need to do: `context.saveGState()` then do your drawing and then do `context.restoreGState()`..

Comment: And do restore state at the end of drawRect?